# Is there a way to create a button on a SharePoint Page without simply linking an image or jpeg?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, button

I am trying to create a button for a SharePoint Site that will open an Excel spreadsheet in Excel online. All of the research I have done on this topic suggests that the easiest way is just to link an image. I would like to use an actual button rather than just linking an image. I use SharePoint Designer 2013, surely there must be a way for me to write a button into the layout of my site manually?...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a button using HTML and set the action to open your document. This can be included on a single page using an embedded code webpart, or you can apply it to many pages using SPD (I'm not 100% familiar with doing this, but believe it should be possible).

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div>
  <button onClick="openFile()" style="height: 35px; padding: 0;"> 
    Open Excel Sheet 
  </button>
</div>

<script>
function openFile() {
  var url = "https://www.google.com";
  var win = window.open(url,"_blank");
  win.focus();
};
</script>
```

Or alternatively you could try something like this (credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link):

```
<form action="http://google.com">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to Google" />
</form>
```

In either case, you would replace the url to google with your .xlsx file's URL.